# Xpath Query to Loop Multiple Child Node

Tags: xpath

```
 <Sections>
<Classes>
  <Class>
      <ClassStd>VI</ClassStd>
      <ClassName>XYZ</ClassName>
  </Class>
  <Class>
      <ClassStd>VII</ClassStd>
      <ClassName>ABC</ClassName>
  </Class>
</Classes>
<Classes>
  <Class>
      <ClassStd>VIII</ClassStd>
      <ClassName>EFG</ClassName>
  </Class>
  <Class>
      <ClassStd>IX</ClassStd>
      <ClassName>MNO</ClassName>
  </Class>
</Classes>
</Sections>
```

I want  to get the **ClassName** values (XYZ,ABC,EfG,MNO) using Xpath. I tried using 
`//Sections/Classes/Class/*/ClassName/text()` and other Xpath queries but i'm not getting desired results. I want to loop through every **Classes** and Every **Class** and get the **ClassName** values. Since the number of Classes or Class is fixed i have to loop till the end to get Values. How i can construct such a loop in Xpath ?

Comment: `ClassName` doesn't seem to be child of `Class`, so there is no need in adding `Class` to your xpath.

Comment: Sorry. The actual XML is like this

`<Sections>
<Classes>
  <Class>
      <ClassStd>VI</ClassStd>
      <ClassName>XYZ</ClassName>
  </Class>
  <Class>
      <ClassStd>VII</ClassStd>
      <ClassName>ABC</ClassName>
  </Class>
</Classes>
<Classes>
  <Class>
      <ClassStd>VIII</ClassStd>
      <ClassName>EFG</ClassName>
  </Class>
  <Class>
      <ClassStd>IX</ClassStd>
      <ClassName>MNO</ClassName>
  </Class>
</Classes>
</Sections>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your xpath to:

```
//sections/classes/classname/text()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The XML looks like this 

`<Sections>
<Classes>
  <Class>
      <ClassStd>VI</ClassStd>
      <ClassName>XYZ</ClassName>
  </Class>
  <Class>
      <ClassStd>VII</ClassStd>
      <ClassName>ABC</ClassName>
  </Class>
</Classes>
<Classes>
  <Class>
      <ClassStd>VIII</ClassStd>
      <ClassName>EFG</ClassName>
  </Class>
  <Class>
      <ClassStd>IX</ClassStd>
      <ClassName>MNO</ClassName>
  </Class>
</Classes>
</Sections>`

`//sections/classes/class/classname/text()` gives me only the first match